# Applocker custom extension (Java, CPL, MSC etc.)

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

We have a Terminal server and want to prevent users from running inappropriate software.
Previously we used Software Restriction Policies for this purpose.

Now, Microsoft seems to recommend Applocker instead. However we found no possibilities to add custom extensions like JAR, CPL, MSC etc. which was possible in Software Restriction Policies.

Do you know how to add custom extensions to the Applocker policies in Windows 2008?
Or how can we block custom script interpreters like Perl etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, there is no way to extend Applockr with custom extensions unless you insert Applocker filter into applications that handle these extensions.